# add line of code to multiple py files to specific area

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, error-handling, text-editor

I have like a hundred python files where there is a try/except set.  I need to add 1 line of code to all of the except sections.  Everything I have tried has resulted in either a problem with indenting (Some files the except clause has a different indent)

I have been trying to come up with a script but haven't had any luck getting it to work.  Any suggestions?

I'm using visual studio code but can use any other editor. Was trying to do it by writing a Python script but I don't figure it out yet maybe I could just do it with the UI.

Comment: This is more of a text editor/ide question than a programming question. What OS and editor are you using?

Comment: Windows.  I'm using visual studio code really I can use any editor

Comment: It would help to be able to see a couple of examples of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following script,

```py
import ast
import os

new_line = ast.parse("print('error occurred')").body[0]

def modify_file(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        tree = ast.parse(f.read())

    for node in ast.walk(tree):
        if isinstance(node, ast.ExceptHandler):
            node.body.append(new_line)

    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        f.write(ast.unparse(tree))


for filename in os.listdir("."):
    if filename.endswith(".py"):
        modify_file(filename)
```

Also [Multiple selections (multi-cursor)](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_multiple-selections-multicursor) will help too.